# How do I prevent the installation of just a few specific apps on my android phone?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, google-apps, vpn

I basically want to prevent myself from installating VPNs and a few social networking sites like Quora and Reddit , every other app is fine

Comment: Who are you preventing? Yourself, a child in your family, employees using company owned equipment?

Comment: I am preventing myself